# @input variable is undefined when trying to print its values in ngOnit of the child component

Tags: angular

I have implemented an angular 10 application that contains a parent component customer and child component createcustomer. The parent component contains a table that lists  all the customers and clicking on edit link on the table passes the data to the child component. As you can see the parent method editCustomer is called that tries to initialise the @input variable.
At the moment my child component @Input value is undefined. I can see the values of the object in the parent component. Not sure why the input variable not getting initialised. Could somebody throw light on this please

Parent component

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService } from '../../services/customer/customer.service';
import { ICustomer } from '../../models/customer.model';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CreateCustomerComponent } from '../create-customer/create-customer.component';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.scss']
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  customerDetails: ICustomer[];
  customer: ICustomer;
  public modal: any;
  totalItems: number;
  maxSize = 5;
  term: string;
  isEdit: boolean;

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService,
              public modalService: NgbModal) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCustomerDetails();
  }

  getCustomerDetails(): void {
    this.customerService.getCustomerDetails()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.customerDetails = data;
        this.totalItems = data.length;
      }
      );
  }

  public addCustomer(): void {
    this.isEdit = false;
    this.openModal();
  }

  public editCustomer(custDetails: ICustomer): void {
   this.isEdit = true;
   this.openModal();
   this.customer = custDetails;
   console.log(this.customer);
  }

  private openModal(): void {
    this.modal = this.modalService.open(CreateCustomerComponent,
      { size: 'fullscreen', centered: true, backdrop: 'static' });
  }
}
```

Parent component html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here" [(ngModel)]="term">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btnAddCustomer" (click)="addCustomer()"> Add Customer (Template Driven) </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div *ngIf="customerDetails" style="height: 700px;  overflow-y:auto">
        <table id="customerdetails-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Contact Name</th>
            <th>Contact Title</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Postal Code</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Fax</th>
            <th>View Order</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let custDetails of customerDetails">
              <td>{{custDetails.customerId}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.companyName}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.contactName}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.contactTitle}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.address}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.city}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.region}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.postalCode}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.country}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.phone}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.fax}}</td>
              <td>
                <a [routerLink]="'/customers'" class="table-row-action edit-action"  (click)="editCustomer(custDetails)">
                  edit
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
      <pagination [totalItems]="totalItems" [itemsPerPage]="5" [maxSize]="maxSize"></pagination>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<app-create-customer [isEdit]="isEdit" [customer]="customer"></app-create-customer>
```

Child component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService } from '../../services/customer/customer.service';
import { ICustomer } from '../../models/customer.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-customer',
  templateUrl: './create-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-customer.component.scss']
})
export class CreateCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() isEdit: boolean;
  @Input() customer: ICustomer;
  constructor(private customerDetailsService: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Inside create customer component' + this.customer);
  }


}
```

Comment: What happens if you set isEdit to false or true? I mean at the same time as declaration

Comment: Consider making a [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) example of your problem so the problem is more obvious.

Comment: consider make a setter in your input https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter or intercept the changes https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-ngonchanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you'd explicitly invoke the modal selector in the parent template when it's initialized in the parent `openModal()` function. You could remove the component selector from the parent template, and set the modal input variables in the parent controller.

Try the following

Parent component controller

```js
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  public editCustomer(custDetails: ICustomer): void {
    this.isEdit = true;
    this.customer = custDetails;     // <-- initialize the `customer` variable before opening modal
    this.openModal();
    console.log(this.customer);
  }

  private openModal(): void {
    this.modal = this.modalService.open(CreateCustomerComponent,
      { size: 'fullscreen', centered: true, backdrop: 'static' }
    );

    this.modal.componentInstance.customer = this.customer;    // <-- send input here
    this.modal.componentInstance.isEdit = this.isEdit;
  }
}
```

Parent component template

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  ...
  </div>
</div>

<!-- don't invoke modal component here -->
```

#### Update: Emit values from modal to parent

Angular `EventEmitters` are extensions of RxJS `Subject`. As such, you could directly subscribe to them in the parent similar to `@Input` variables using `componentInstance`. And you could use Modal `close()` function to close the modal from parent component.

Try the following

Parent component controller

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  completed$ = new Subject<any>();      // <-- use to close subscriptions
  modal: any;

  constructor(private _NgbModal: NgbModal) { }

  openModal() {
    this.modal = this._NgbModal.open(NgModalComponent, {
      size: 'fullscreen', centered: true, backdrop: 'static' 
    });

    this.modal.componentInstance.customer = customer;

    this.modal.componentInstance.someValue.pipe(   // <-- subscribe to an `@Output()` from modal component
      takeUntil(this.completed$)                   // <-- close subscription when `completed$` emits
    ).subscribe(
      value => {
        if (value === 'close') {
          this.closeModal();
        }
      }
    );
  }

  closeModal() {                                 // <-- close modal
    this.modal.close('Close click');
    this.completed$.next();                      // <-- close active emitter subscriptions
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.completed$.complete();                  // <-- close impending subscriptions 
  }
}
```

Modal component controller

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class CreateCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() isEdit: boolean;
  @Input() customer: ICustomer;

  @Output() someValue = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private customerDetailsService: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Inside create customer component' + this.customer);
  }

  emitValue() {
    this.someValue.emit('close');
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, I dont stick the childselector in the component markup. How do you retrieve values passed to the child component otherwise

Comment: As shown in the `openModal()` function, we could use Modal [`componentInstance`](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal-ref.ts#L42) to pass the data to the modal.

Comment: I meant how would you retrieve the componentinstance in child component ?

Comment: You don't have to modify the current child component code. The `@Input()` variables are assigned values using the `componentInstance` from the parent. With the above code, the `console.log()` in your child should already print the `consumer` (it may print `[Object object]`) instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I can see object object now in the child component. But jsut confused which approach is best suited. The approach mentioned by @Poul Kruijt works fine as well.

Comment: Hi Micahel whilst your approach sounds good, while implementing input variable, I stumbled across a problem while using the output emitter. Doesn't the output emitter require child selector markup in the parent template for it to work. I need to close my modal dialog and the method to close the dialog is in the parent . How would I then close the dialog using your approach

Comment: @Tom: `EventEmitter` s are extension of RxJS `Subject`. So you could subscribe to it in the parent component. I've updated the answer. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: The `someValue` I used is an example. Please replace it with your own `EventEmitter` from the modal. If the error still persists, it might be a TS Lint error. In that case, the code will compile.

Comment: thanks a ton. It works for me. Its something new that I have learnt. I was always under the impression I need to use child component selector in the markup to pass values but didnt come across the popup implementation scenario

Comment: Yes I had figured that somevalue issue. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The child component `app-create-customer` is created and initialized when the parent component is created. The `this.customer` on the parent is only set in the `editCustomer` method.

The `ngOnInit` hook is called when the component is created, not when you set some input variable. For that you should use the `ngOnChanges` hook. To check which input has changed. Depending on your needs, you can either use an `*ngIf`, to only show the component when a customer has been selected, or use `ngOnChanges` to act upon changes on the input:

solution 1:

```
<app-create-customer *ngIf="customer" [customer]="customer"></app-create-customer>
```

---

solution 2:

```
export class CreateCustomerComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() isEdit: boolean;
  @Input() customer: ICustomer;

  constructor(private customerDetailsService: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.customer && this.customer) {
      console.log('A customer is here', this.customer);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Solution 2 works but solution 1 for some reason doesn't. Nevermind as i am not too concerned about that. I can see solution proposed by @Michael D works and now confused which is the best approach

Comment: @Tom I missed the fact that you were working with a modal, in that case, Michael D's answer is better

Comment: Thanks Poul for letting me know

Answer (score -2):

The `@Input()` value is always **undefined**.

You're getting **undefined** in ngOnInit because at the point when the component is initialized you haven't actually passed in the **customer** value.

Try this in your Child Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService } from '../../services/customer/customer.service';
import { ICustomer } from '../../models/customer.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-customer',
  templateUrl: './create-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-customer.component.scss']
})
export class CreateCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() isEdit: boolean;
  @Input() customer: ICustomer;
  constructor(private customerDetailsService: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
       console.log('Inside create customer component' + this.customer);
    });        
  }


}
```